# @PostConstruct didn't get called by JSF if ManagedBean is inside jar library

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, postconstruct

I'm running with the following problem.

I have a few Managed Beans that are shared between, at this moment, two JSF applications. As I don't want to copy and paste the code in the two (more in the coming future) I've put this shared managed beans inside a JAR library. I've followed this blog: http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/custom-component-library/

Well, even if I put the faces-config.xml inside JAR/META-INF/ the @ManagedBean and @ViewScoped didn't work. I couldn't realise why, but if I register the beans in faces-config.xml (JAR ones, not WAR ones) this problem goes away.

I could live with this, but for my surprise the @PostConstruct annotation didn't get called for this managed beans inside JAR library. I don't get any error, warning or else. I suppose that the beans are getting loaded, but the their annotations aren't being processed.

Have anyone faced this?

My environment:
Glassfish 3.1.1 (build 12)
JSF 2.1.3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Then the `@PostConstruct` annotation has not been scanned. This is result of the same problem which caused that your `@ManagedBean` annotation and likes have not been scanned.

There are several causes of this problem:

1. You used Mojarra 2.1.0 on Jetty/Tomcat/JBoss AS. This is a very specific bug in the annotation scanner. See [issue 1937](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1937).
2. Your `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` file has a `metadata-complete="true"` attribute. This conflicts the 1st requirement as outlined in [JSF 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html):

   > ### 11.5.1 Requirements for scanning of classes for annotations
   >
   > - If the `<faces-config>` element in the `WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` file contains `metadata-complete` attribute whose value is `“true”`, the implementation must not perform annotation scanning on any classes except for those classes provided by the implementation itself. Otherwise, continue as follows.
   > - If the runtime discovers a conflict between an entry in the Application Configuration Resources and an annotation, the
   >     entry in the Application Configuration Resources takes precedence.
   > - All classes in `WEB-INF/classes` must be scanned.
   > - For every jar in the application's `WEB-INF/lib` directory, if the jar contains a `“META-INF/faces-config.xml”`
   >     file or a file that matches the regular expression `“.*\.faces-config.xml”` (even an empty one), all classes in that jar must be scanned.
3. Your JAR file is not been dropped in `/WEB-INF/lib`, but somewhere else in the classpath. This conflicts the 4th requirement as outlined above.
4. Your webapp's `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` and/or your JAR's `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` is not JSF 2.x compatible. It must not contain a JSF 1.x specific `<faces-config>` declaration, but a JSF 2.x specific one.

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <faces-config
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
       version="2.0">
   </faces-config>
   ```

   The one in JAR's `/META-INF` is allowed to be completely empty.

Cause 1 can be scratched in your particular case as you're using Mojarra 2.1.3 on Glassfish. I'll bet it to be the other causes.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for answering. Well, the faces-config files (JAR and WAR) are pointing to JSF 2.x and both don't use metadata-complete, so I'm lost. I suppose that #1 is the problem because I didn't pack the JAR inside WAR but I'd deployed it as a library in ...domains/domain1/lib.

Comment: Oh, I totally didn't expect that. Why did you put the JAR there? The JSF2 spec mandates that the JAR must be in `/WEB-INF/lib`. I improved the answer to add it as point 3.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. My mistake. Explaining why: just because I don't want to "replicate" jars ... I'm using Primefaces too and I put it in the domain/lib too. It works, so as I am new in JSF world I thought that I could do the same with my library.

Comment: PF libraries do not contain any managed beans and everything is registered in xml files. I'd just bundle the JAR in your webapp.

Answer (score 8):

Also note that post-construct method must not be declared to throw any checked exception. Message from `stderr`:

```
Method 'public void my.app.MyBean.postConstruct() throws java.lang.Exception' marked with the 'javax.annotation.PostConstruct' annotation cannot declare any checked exceptions. This method will be ignored.
```